# Datepicker not displaying when referenced with a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When I navigate to the file below (datepicker.jsp) the datepicker is displayed and works as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
@import "./jquery.datepick.package-4.0.4/jquery.datepick.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.datepick.package-4.0.4/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.datepick.package-4.0.4/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepick();
});

function showDate(date) {
    alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
</script>

<title>jQuery Datepicker</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>A popup datepicker <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

However when I embed the page in a tab like so -

```
<s:div id="three" label="Add" href="/Dates/datepicker.jsp">
</s:div>
```

The date picker popup is not displayed.

Do I need to reference the div within the function call to -$('#datepicker').datepick(); ?

Thanks for any help.

Ok,

Here is the link to the tab -

```
<div dojoType="struts:BindDiv" id="two" label="Add" href="/Dates/DatePicker.jsp" showError="true" parseContent="true">
</div>
```

And here is DatePicker.jsp -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
@import "./jquery.datepick.package-4.0.4/jquery.datepick.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.datepick.package-4.0.4/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.datepick.package-4.0.4/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepick();
});

function showDate(date) {
    alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
</script>

<title>jQuery Datepicker</title>
</head>

<body>
 <p>A popup datepicker <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks again

Comment: can you include a snippet of the generated html?

Comment: Here is the like to the tab -

Comment: Question edited to include generated html

Comment: I've edited your question because none of your HTML displays unless you select it and click on the code icon that looks like `{}`. Please do this for all code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed to using google jquery plugin and seems to be working well.